# Java Generic confusion on wild card

Tags: java

I am learning generic and got struck at some point.here is my class

```
public class MyValidator{

    private Class providerClass;

    public MyValidator(Container container){
       setProviderClass(container.getInstanc(ValidationProvider.class),"my.providerClass");
   }

    public void setProviderClass(Class<? extends ValidationProvider> providerClass)
    {
        this.providerClass = providerClass;
    }

}
```

Signature of container is

```
 <T> T getInstance(Class<T> type, String name)
Gets an instance of the given dependency which was declared in ContainerBuilder.
```

Container is an inbuild DI mechanism of the platform i am using, but when i call the setter method from inside my constructor i am getting following exception in Eclipse

> The method setProviderClass(Class) in the type MyValidator is not applicable for the arguments (ValidationProvider)

I know i am not following the contract properly but not sure how to do this.My intentions are to set the class at run time and it should accept all those implimentation who impliments `ValidationProvider` which is an interface.

Answer (score 1):

getInstance(Class type, String name) return T not Class -> an instance of ValidationProvider not a class object.

That's what the exception message says: you need a Class object but you're passing a ValidationProvider object.